# ObservableArray not binding to GUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, laravel-3

I'm new with knockout.js and trying to fix data binding on a site that is build on Laravel and is using knockout.js.

Observable array works well and items can be pushed and popped without issues. The problem is with the binding to GUI. When items are pushed to array those are added to GUI, but nothing else works, like removing items, and also when adding more items later on those are added on the top of the GUI element list, not added after existing items on the GUI. The observable array is having correct items after push/pop/removeall, its just not reflecting to GUI.

I guess that the problem is that observable array is not binded to GUI, but I cannot figure out what could be wrong.

Stripped code:

```
Chat.init = function(){
    Chat.viewModel = new Chat.ViewModel;
    ko.applyBindings(Chat.viewModel, $('#msg_canvas').get(0));
};


Chat.ViewModel = function(){

    self.messages = ko.observableArray();

    self.setMessages = function(msgs){
        _.each(msgs, function(msg){
            self.messages.push(msg);
        });
    };

    self.clearMessages = function(data, e){
        self.messages.removeAll();
    }

}
```

`clearMessages` is called via `onclick: data-bind="click: $parent.clearMessages`

The HTML is this:

```
<div id="msg_canvas"  class="msg-wrap col-md-12" 
     style="height:274px;overflow-y:scroll;" data-bind="foreach: messages">

     <div class="media msg">
           <div class="media-body">
                  <span data-bind="text: sent_at"></span>
                  <small class="col-lg-10" data-bind="text: message"></small>
           </div>
     </div>
```

Any help or pointer to what could be causing the problem would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE: added inner HTML which was not included to post before

Comment: Are you using underscore js too?

Comment: Yes, underscore js is also used on the site. I haven't check yet if its related to this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a control inside the `div` to hold your messages, like a `<span>` or `<p>`. Otherwise, you're simply doing the `foreach` without outputting the values. So your `div` should look something like this, using `$data` to access the value:

```
<div id="msg_canvas" data-bind="foreach: messages">
  <p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
</div>
```

Here's a working snippet based on your code (`setMessages` slightly modified / hard coded with values):

```js
ViewModel = function(){

    self.messages = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.setMessages = function(){
      var msgs = ['message','message','message'];
        _.each(msgs, function(msg){
            self.messages.push(msg + ' ' + self.messages().length);
        });
    };

    self.clearMessages = function(data, e){
        self.messages.removeAll();
    }
    
    self.removeMessage = function(item){
        self.messages.remove(item);
    }

};


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="msg_canvas"  class="msg-wrap col-md-12" 
     style="height:274px;overflow-y:scroll;border: black solid 1px" data-bind="foreach: messages">
  <p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
  <input type="button" data-bind="click: removeMessage" value="Remove Item" />  
</div>

<input type="button" data-bind="click: setMessages" value="Add Message" />
<input type="button" data-bind="click: clearMessages" value="Remove All" />
```

Comment: I have the div holding the messages and it gets populated correctly when pushing items first time. If pushing more items later the items are added on top of the div not on the bottom after existing items, also removeall/pop doesn't remove any items. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Laowai updated the post to demonstrate items added to end of list and remove all and remove individual item using `self.messages.remove(item);`. If this doesn't help, it would be worthwhile recreating the issue in a snippet/jsfiddle.

Comment: The problem is that the site is very complex and this is just part of the functionality. I'm sure that your example will work, but for some reason the binding is not working on my site. I doubt that I could replicate the issue with snippet/jsfiddle as there are so much other stuff.

Comment: @Laowai it's worth while trying as you usually stumble across the offending piece of code when you start stripping it down. Either that, or comment out all of the code and start re-implementing it a piece at a time until it works or something breaks it.

Comment: well, you are right on that. I will try to make a strip down version first which works and then see where it breaks. I will comment here if I will get some version working. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: BIG thanks to you!! I followed your advice and find out that jQuery css emoticons plugin was causing the problem. Not sure why it happens, but after not calling emoticons for the observable content everything works. I spent lot of time on this so I'm really really thankful for your simple yet so right advice. I will accept your solution as it shows how the foreach binding is done.

Comment: @Laowai no worries, glad it's sorted